# Remove default jdk 1.7 version and set 1.6 on windows

Tags: environment-variables, java

I had installed both version of jdk `1.6` and `1.7` and have projects which are developed on version `1.6`. So I need `1.6`. I set path in environmental variable for version `1.6`. But still showing version `1.7` when I used `java -version` from `cmd`.

I want to make default version of jdk `1.6` on my computer. I am using `windows 7`.

**NOTE:** I do not want to uninstall `1.7` and I do not have administrative privileges.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While instalation Java exe files are copied to *windows System32* folder, Check this location(`C:\Windows\System32`) *java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe* are available there.

What you need to do now is, replace this exe's with jdk 1.6 exe's and open a new command prompt and check the version.

Comment: Having same issue.. but I dont find exe mentioned by you at System32

Comment: I do not have at this place even ! ..but I did locate the mentioned exe, accidentaly at C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Answer (score 2):

First of all be sure that the java 1.6 home path is put in the beginning of Windows path, because the first met path is used. If you have done that try to start the command prompt NOT as an administrator and check the java version. Strangely I had the same issue and I succeeded to start the java 1.6 version only in a command prompt without administrative privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your response. And yes, I do not have administrative privileges. Our system administrator is not present right now. So I want to change it. But I checked using `echo %PATH%` it is not displaying vrsion `1.7`

Answer (score 2):

Add the JavaPath\bin in PATH variable at the start of PATH.